# how system.in represents keyboard?

Tags: java, io

I am new in JAVA and i came across a statement in CORE JAVA BlackBook :

"System.in represents Keyboard."

I know that System is a class which has a inputStreamReader reference "IN".
kindly tell me how it represents Keyboard.
I can not map the sentence with a technical explanation.

Thank you

Comment: What you type on your keyboard ends up there.

Answer (score 0):

in/out - inputStreamReader  and outputStreamWriter.

in is console input stream reader. So Keyboard is the input provider for that.

Answer (score 0):

`System.in` refers to the the standard input device on your computer , which is normally a keyboard . 
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System . in ) ;` is synonymous to saying listen to the input from the default input device on this system ( normally a keyboard ) .

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is a white lie.

The `System.in` stream is linked to the *standard input* of your application. By default, for console applications, the standard input is whatever is typed at the console, and that is usually done with the keyboard. But it doesn't have to be that way:

- stdin can be redirected, e.g. by calling your program on the command line with a redirection operator: `java YourClass < input.txt`
- There are other ways to get input to your console. Your terminal emulator probably supports copy&paste, which you can do with the mouse only.